# ifdef not working in resource file

Tags: c++, gcc, g++4.8, windres

I'm trying to use:

```
#include "Resource.h"

#ifdef __x86_64
IDR_D3D9X43     BINARY              "D3DX9_43_64.dll"
#else
IDR_D3D9X43     BINARY              "D3DX9_43_32.dll"
#endif
```

in my resource file (.rc). When I compile for x64, it should include the x64 resource. When I compile for x32, it should include the x32 resource. However, it does not..

It is being compiled using:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -O2 -m64 -std=c++11  -c C:\Users\School\Desktop\TestLoader\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o
windres.exe --target=pe-x86-64  -J rc -O coff -i C:\Users\School\Desktop\TESTLO~1\RESOUR~1\Resource.rc -o obj\Release\Resources\Resource.res
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Release\TestLoader.exe obj\Release\main.o  obj\Release\Resources\Resource.res -s -m64 -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

Output file is bin\Release\TestLoader.exe with size 3.02 MB

for x64 compilation and it uses:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -O2 -m32 -std=c++11  -c C:\Users\School\Desktop\TestLoader\main.cpp -o obj\Release\main.o
windres.exe --target=pe-i386  -J rc -O coff -i C:\Users\School\Desktop\TESTLO~1\RESOUR~1\Resource.rc -o obj\Release\Resources\Resource.res
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\Release\TestLoader.exe obj\Release\main.o  obj\Release\Resources\Resource.res -s -m32 -static -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++
```

for x32 compilation.

Any ideas why it does not conditionally include the specific resource? It always includes the first resource at the top of the file.. aka the x64 one.

Comment: your compiler is not getting macro __x86_64. can you check is it defined or not

Comment: It is defined because this macro works for the code. Just not for the resources. Also tried `_WIN64`.

Comment: Compiling a resource file is a different step with a different compiler then compiling a code file.  Just because a given macro is defined within the code compiler does not guarantee that the same macro will be defined within the resource compiler.

Comment: Doing some searches, it seems that `x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++.exe` is a 64bit compiler and `i686-w64-mingw32-g++.exe` is the 32bit compiler.  That might explain why you are always getting `__x86_64` defined - you are using the 64bit compiler to compile a 32bit target.

Comment: No because I am using `-m32` and `-m64` to compile. These switches allow me to compile x32 and x64 code in Mingw-Builds 4.8.1. I finally solved it though. You were right that it is a different step and that the macro isn't passed down from the code-compiler to the resource-compiler. I had to add `-DMyDefinition` to the `windres.exe` command-line.